# Python to exe module dependency

Tags: python, pyinstaller

If I make an exe from python modules and let's say the modules are depending on a external library (let's say pandas) and then i run the exe in a different PC do i have to install pandas or even **python** in that PC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. With some libraries you have to add dlls like e.g. PyQt / PySide (but not Panadas)

Comment: do i need to install python in new pc? or the exe will work like a normal application

Comment: Python does not need to be installed. It works like a normal program.

Comment: okay thanks, and one more doubt. I am using eel library to make a desktop application. Can I distribute it like a normal app without even installing a single package in new PC? I am usin pyinstaller to package the bundle in onefile

Comment: That should work (if not you have to see if there are any dll files required) You can also test it by running your program in a windows sandbox

Comment: indeed, the dlls am seeing are part of system32 so it should work, the doubt i was having was, I read that pyinstaller packaged exe first extract python modules in a temp directory and then execute, that's wwhy i was comfused if it directly work or not. Correctme if i read it wrong. Btw thanks for helpin out

Comment: Yes that's right. but if you compile a py file to an exe (without -F) you will see a file python.dll and that is the interpreter. I'm glad to hear that I was able to help you :)